# How to center a UILabel in a UIToolbar

Tags: ios

I have a UIToolbar in the interface builder. I made a connection to the UIToolbar using IBOutlets. In my code in the initWithCoder and viewDidLoad event I try to access the bounds.size.width property of the UIToolbar and it says 0. Eventually, I would like to center a UILabel inside the UIToolbar.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `UIBarButtomItem` like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *flexible1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *titleButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Label String" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *flexible2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexible1, titleButton, flexible2, nil]];
```